# How to remove external js file on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, button, events

```
   suraj.js
  var mins=.1;
    var secs=mins60;
    function countdown() {
        setTimeout('Decrement()',60);
    }
    function Decrement() {
        if(document.getElementById) {
            minutes=document.getElementById(minutes);
            seconds=document.getElementById(seconds);
            if(seconds59) {
                seconds.value=secs;
            }
            else {
                minutes.value=getminutes();
                seconds.value=getseconds();
            }
            if(mins1) {
                minutes.style.color=red;
                seconds.style.color=red;
            }
            if(mins0) {
                 alert('time up');
                minutes.value=0;
                seconds.value=0;
            }
            else {
                secs--;
                setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
            }
        }
    }
 
    function getminutes() {
        mins=Math.floor(secs60);
        return mins;
    }
 
    function getseconds() {
        return secs-Math.round(mins60);
    }
```

```
!DOCTYPE html
html xmlns=httpwww.w3.org1999xhtml
head

!--LINK external js--
script type=textjavascript src=suraj.js data-scriptid=MyDomScriptscript

!-- Link jquery --
script type=textjavascript src=httpajax.googleapis.comajaxlibsjquery1.7.1jquery.min.jsscript

head
body onload=countdown()!-- Your web--
   
   button id=myBtnTry itbutton


 div style=display flex; width80%;
                justify-contentcenter; padding-top 0%;
        Time Left 
    div
    div style=display flex; width80%;
                justify-contentcenter; padding-top 0%;
        input id=minutes type=text style=width 3%; border none; font-size 16px;
                      font-weight bold; color black;
        font size=5
            
        font
        input id=seconds type=text style=width 3%; border none; font-size 16px;
                      font-weight bold; color black;
    div
    script type=textjavascript

document.getElementById(myBtn).addEventListener(click, function() {

let domScripts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scriptid=MyDomScript]');
   domScripts.forEach(function(s) {
   s.remove();
});
});
script
body
html
```

How can i stop the timer on button press that will destroy js imported...or any manual way?

I want to remove script tag from DOM && completely erase the variables or events already defined by the script.

Comment: You can't remove JavaScript code from the file that is already loaded and executed. You can only remove the script tag but it will not remove the running script. But please describe what is exactly you want to do, since this may be [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Ok i think Your sayings are practical one as remove method cannot access rendered ones, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can only remove CSS that was added to the page and it will be removed, but with JavaScript, you can't. Maybe try to explain what you want to do, since as I've written you may have XY problem you ask about the solution, not about the problem you have.